# How do you copy a test from one .SIDE file to another?

Tags: selenium-ide

is there a way to drag and drop a test from `Project1.side` to `Project2.side`?

A graphical way of doing so would be ideal.

Or would I need to export and then re-import? If I did, so which formats do I need to choose? (there are 6 languages to choose from and 3 checkboxes)

> C# NUnit, C# xUnit, Java JUnit, JavaScript Mocha, Python pytest, Ruby RSpec

Options:

> Include origin tracing code comments,
> Include step description as a separate comment
> Export for use on Selenium Grid